# Invocar un script de JS con un disparador desde php

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando ejecutar un archivo JS cuando un `trigger` se ingrese a su tabla, ejecute un `location.reload()` pero no tengo ninguna idea de como hacerlo, ya intente usando un header, pero aparece en texto plano aparece *location.reload* así como un texto así es mi código por el momento, el archivo recargar.js solo tiene `location.reload();`

ARCHIVO DE TRIGGER:

```
<?php
include('./../../conexion.php');

$q = "SELECT id, fecha FROM trigger_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1"; // Extraer el ultimo gatillo
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    header("Location: ./recargar.js");
}
    
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Algunas ideas? Gracias

Comment: Creo que el problema es que nunca le estás indicando que es un `<script>`. Crea un `recargar.html` con la etiqueta `<script>` y ejecuta el código JS adentro

Comment: Hola Liyo, ya hice lo que me dijiste gracias y funciona, pero me ayudarias en que cada vez que haya un nuevo trigger se ejecute el script? Muchas Gracias

Comment: David, el `trigger` se ejecuta directo en el servidor (es un disparador automatizado, como un SP). El código JS en el `frontend`. Creo que estas confundiendo el concepto de `trigger`, ¿puede ser? Si lo que deseas es que se ejecute un código de JS luego que el **motor de la base de datos** ejecuta un `trigger`, lamento no poder ayudarte. Si lo que quieres es que cada vez que ejecutas una **consulta** desde `php` suceda esto que vimos recién, pues debes repetir este paso. Salvo que no esté entendiendo tu problema. Si me explicaras mas, tal vez te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: Sin embargo, creo que hay mejores maneras de actualizar la página sin recargarla, ya se viene haciendo desde la época de Jquery con AJAX o ahora directamente con JS puro.

Comment: Basicamente lo que necesito es que cuando se genere un nuevo un trigger me reinicie un temporizador hecho en JS